# Customize the bibliography numbering

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I've only one page of the bibliography on beamer which I want to remove its numbering.

I'm getting as title : `Bibliography I` which I want it to became `Bibliography`.

How to do that please?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a minimal working example (MWE, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. It is very hard to use guess what might be the problem without having the slightest idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Without any real informations about your code, I can only look into a crystal ball an guess.

But based on the variety of your other questions by you, my best guess is, that you might want to change.

```
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{Bibliography}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
```

into

```
\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{Bibliography}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
```

In the first case, your slide is only the first one and might be followed by more (depending on the length of your bibliography). Therefore the is followed by the counter `I`.

Comment: That's exactly how am I proceeding (first proposition). And, I have in the preamble these lines `\usepackage{biblatex}\addbibresource{bibli.bib}` Which I cannot remove them from.